# Exposing variables from main.js to other scripts in a vue-cli project

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I need to access the Vue instance, declared inside `main.js` of my vue-cli project, from outside the webpack-generated .js file. In `main.js`, I have:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

However, because webpack wraps this code in a function and minifies it, the vm variable is never accessible from outside the script. How can I fix that and ensure the vm variable can be accessed from other scripts?

All webpack settings are the defaults provided by vue-cli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could export the Vue instance and import it in the other scripts.

```
export const vm = new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

To access it in the other scripts, simply use

```
import { vm } from 'path/main.js'
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it issues an error message stating that the target script ('./app.js') does not contain an export with the name I specified. I should mention that other scripts (not other modules packed by webpack into the same script) need to see it, so the import must happen after webpack has packed it into app.js.

Comment: I added `library: 'myLibraryName'` in the `output` section of the webpack configuration in vue.config.js and it works now. I can now use myLibraryName as a global variable after importing the script. Thanks for the information, it really helped!


For those wondering how a webpack output file can be converted into a library,  see this: https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/

Comment: I'm glad to have been able to help, and that figured out the following problem yourself. Upvoted so others can see.

Answer (score 1):

You can put it on `window`

```
window.myComponent = new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```